# jQuery plugin to select value inside input

Tags: jquery

How do I select/highlight the default value inside the input on focus?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/321/Using-jQuery-to-Highlight-Select-All-Text-in-a-Textbox):

```
<input type="text" id="txtInput" />
```

and then:

```
$('#txtInput').click(function() { 
    var textbox = $(this);
    textbox.focus();
    textbox.select();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).select();
});
```